# Cygin Curl URL Retrieval, Specific Ranges and Folder Placement for Images

Tags: bash, image, curl, cygwin, image-stitching

I have a script I've been using for Cygwin that grabs URLs and saves them to the default folder. What I want to do is specify and automate this further so I don't have to mess with it so much.

Here is the current script:

```
curl "http://ids.lib.harvard.edu/ids/view/Converter?id=[45477234-45477312]&c=jpgnocap&s=2&r=0&x=0&y=0&w=2400&h=2400" -o "#1.jpg"
```

What this does is save a specific image in a limited window as a jpg in the default folder. The "x=" and "y=" determine where the first pixel value on this large (like 7000x9000) image is. I have been trying to piece these images together through stitching.

I want to automate this by incrementing the x and y values by specific amounts, that being 2400, each time it comes around. I know how to do ranges, but I want to do the additions of 2400 (0, 2400, 4800, 7200, 9600) and it appears putting commas into a square bracket doesn't work.

In addition I want to make sure that when it returns to each URL it doesn't save over itself. I want a grouped set of images with endings ( (0), (1), etc) which I can use as a guide to put it all together. (PS If you know a good way to automate THIS process, I'd love to hear).

I imagine this fix is pretty simple, but I'm new to bash scripts. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

So the obvious way is just to use nested loops for a gridlike splicing, here's an example where we first read the max x and y coordinates from the input (`-x` and `-y`) and then loop through the possibilities one column at a time starting from `0,0` all the way to `$x_max, $y_max` :

```
#! /bin/bash
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -x )
            x_max=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -y )
            y_max=$2
            shift
            ;;
        * )
            echo "unknown option" && exit 2
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
for (( xcord = xcounter = 0; xcord <= $x_max; xcord+=2400, xcounter+=1 )); do
    for (( ycord = ycounter = 0; ycord <= $y_max; ycord+=2400, ycounter+=1 )); do
        curl "http://ids.lib.harvard.edu/ids/view/Converter?id=[45477234-45477312]&c=jpgnocap&s=2&r=0&x=${xcord}&y=${ycord}&w=2400&h=2400" -o "#${xcounter}_${ycounter}.jpg"
    done
done
```